# Stained my deck and it rained after 19 hours

Tags: staining

I just finished staining my deck with an oil product at 730pm last night. There was rain the next day by 3pm. Will I have problems?

Comment: Light rain, heavy rain, floods?   Not the best timing but might get lucky.  If problems should show in a day.

Comment: What do the directions on the can of stain say about rain?

Comment: It's probably OK.  It may not be as shiny as it otherwise would be.

Comment: Light rain there are some white water marks today :( the can didn’t specify.